# EF6 query with Max and filters

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0

In C# code with EF6 and Sql Server, my goal is to use this query :

```
Select MAX(columnA) from myTable WHERE columnB>5 AND ColumnC=1
```

by using C# code.

Example :

```
SELECT Max(ColumnA) from myTable
```

becomes :
`int max = DbContext.myTable.Max(t => t.ColumnA);`   => works fine, OK

But do you know how to add the where clause into this C# code ???

Erixx

Comment: Between myTable and Max?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put Where first and then Max later  like this

```
int max = DbContext.myTable.Where(it=>it.columnB>5 && it.ColumnC=1).Max(t => t.ColumnA);
```

Comment: Now, i need to use this filter which keep data from the last 30 days, it works as Sql Server query but not into the C# code : it => it.DateCreated >= (Select DATEADD(Month, -1, getdate()))

Comment: Create a variable like this  var thirtyDayAgo = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30); and then  it => it.DateCreated >= thirtyDayAgo

Comment: Nice ! Thank you Toan !!

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `Where` before `Max` (or after, depending on your logic).

```
int max = DbContext.myTable.Where(t => t.ColumnB > 5 && ColumnC == 1).Max(t => t.ColumnA)
```